# all possible combinations of a list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors and I would like to get a list of all possible combinations between the elements of every vector, i.e., combinations of n elements (from a vector) taken two and more than two at a time.

For instance, I have the following list:

```
> DF
$`1`
   A B   C
1 11 2 432

$`2`
   A B   C
2 11 3 432

$`3`
   A B   C
3 13 4 241
```

Here's my code:

```
> d=list()
>   for (j in 1:length(DF)){
+     for (i in 2:length(DF)){
+       d[[j]]=combn(DF[[j]],i,simplify=F)
+     }
+   }
> d
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   A B   C
1 11 2 432

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   A B   C
2 11 3 432

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
   A B   C
3 13 4 241
```

It is wrong, because I just get combinations of three elements taken three at a time. I would have to add combinations of three elements taken two at a time. I just get the last loop value. It is a problem of dimensions inside the loop.

If I run the loop just for i=2, then I get:

```
> d
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   A B
1 11 2

[[1]][[2]]
   A   C
1 11 432

[[1]][[3]]
  B   C
1 2 432


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   A B
2 11 3

[[2]][[2]]
   A   C
2 11 432

[[2]][[3]]
  B   C
2 3 432

....
```

Comment: Are you looking for `combn(DF, 2, FUN = list)`

Comment: Thanks akrun, but the combinations are between elements of every vector. I am going to modify the question.

Comment: @akrun perhaps something `lapply(DF, combn, m = 2, simplify = F)`?

Comment: @jazzurro It could be, let the OP update with the expected output

Comment: Thanks jazzurro, but in this case ncol(DF)=3, so it would be m=2 and m=3. If ncol were 5, it would be m=2,3,4,5

Comment: I have tried: e=c();
for (j in 2:length(DF)){
  e[[j]]=lapply(DF, combn, j, simplify = F) 
} And it works, I have to try it with big data frames. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
lapply(2:3, function(k) { lapply(1:length(DF),function(x){ combn(DF[[x]],k, 
                          simplify = FALSE)})})
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, it works well. I have tried the way in my last comment, but maybe your solution is faster. How can I get row vectors instead of column vectors in your solution

Comment: do you mean that the output shows the names "A", "B", "C"?. In that case, add: `simplify = FALSE` into the `combn` function

Comment: i have added the `simplify` argument to the code block, running it should give you the names now

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I wanted. Thank you everyone, great community.